# address field missing in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I have installed Address Field Module(7.x-1.1+3-dev) in my Drupal 7.38. I installed it just as Drupal instructed. (Download .zip file, unzip, enable in Admin page)

However, when I tried to add address field during adding new content types, I couldn't find address field type! (well, there is a "postal address". But I guess it is not from the address field module; And I could not find my address field in Admin-Configuration)

This is so weird. I have installed my Geofield module exactly the same way, and my Geofiled works perfectly fine. I got my CTools enabled. I even tried address field module of 7.x-1.1 version. But the problem is the same.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I installed on shared host on godaddy.com. It is a central OS linux system.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The postal address is from Address Field Module. Adding it to your content, and when you create the view, you will find that it is actually an address field. I personally think it a little weird. Because I have seen different names for the field (postal address, physical address, address field etc)